Difference of outputs of print of int[] ,String[] and char[] in Java
My question is simple .I know output but i can't know why is different outputs of all of them.
Firstly, i wanted to get output of array what is created newly and is empty .i coded like that:
(https://i.sstatic.net/V40Jw.png)
and i got output like that:
(https://i.sstatic.net/6cJdU.png)
I hope you will take into account that I am just learning Java 1 month

I'm not sure why you're surprised.  If you print an integer zero, you should expect to see 0, and you do.  If you print a character with value 0, you get an ASCII null, and your IDE evidently displays nulls as the slashed box.  If you print an uninitialized string, the Java runtime prints it as the word null.  What were you expecting?

please check and consider this question and its answer: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? || "array what is created newly and is empty" - an array is (and stays) empty only if created with size 0; it is a "number of variables" of the same type, accessed through an index; the number does not change after created. Check the Collection implementing classes, e.g. ArrayList, if you need a collection with variable size: tutorial.

dont post pictures of code, it helps a lot when u just copy and paste it here

Here you have created an array of integers with a length of 2 using new int[2]. In Java, when you initialize an array of integers using new int[2], it initializes each element to its default value, which is 0 for int type.
Same goes for arrays of char and string and as well you have not intitialized any of the arrays that is why you are getting their respective default values as output .
